# p-value of correlation between a partially censored variable and a continuous variable

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

I am looking for a method in R that would return the estimate of correlation between a partially censored variable and a continuous variable **as well as the associated p-value**. There is a package named [SurvCorr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SurvCorr/index.html) which gives me the correlation estimate, but as far as I checked, it does not assign a p-value to the estimate.

Comment: Highly recommend you checkout SO sister site: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user5054  You should edit the body of your question to include a `library` call to that package and an example built with R code and suitable for pasting into an R console session. The documentation says confidence limits are being placed which strongly suggests that it can be hacked with ease to deliver the desired P-value.

Comment: Yes, actually I already asked on stats.stackexchange how I can get the p-values from a known confidence interval.

Comment: I hope you asked a more detailed question than that.